# GOLANG: ERROR :main.go: json.Marshal (value of type func(v any) ([]byte, error)) is not a type MONGO DB

Tags: mongodb, filtro, go, nosql

estoy teniendo un problema en una funcion en Golang.
El objetivo de la funcion es que dado un email, busque en una coleccion de Mongo y me devuelva una lista con todas los objetos que tengan ese email almacenado.

Las estructuras que manejo en la funcion son las siguientes:

```
type Buscar struct{
    Email string `json:"email,omitempty" bson:"email,omitempty"`
}

type Order struct{
    Produc Product
    StatusOrder string `json:"statusorder,omitempty" bson:"statusorder,omitempty"`
    SellerName string  `json:"sellername,omitempty" bson:"sellername,omitempty"`
    Tons        string `json:"tons,omitempty" bson:"tons,omitempty"`
    Id             primitive.ObjectID`json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty`
    
}
```

---

La **funcion donde se produce el error** es la siguiente:

```
func FindOrder(w http.ResponseWriter, r http.Request){
    w.Header().Add("content-type", "application/json")
    var busca Buscar
    var orders [] Order
     = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&busca)
    email := busca.Email
    collection := client.Database("ordersDB").Collection("orders")
    ctx,  := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10time.Second)
    filter := bson.M{"sellername": email}
    options := options.Find()
    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, filter, options)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Err", err)
    }
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var order Order
        cursor.Decode(&order)
        orders = append(orders, order)
    }
    if err := cursor.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
        return
    }
    jsonResult, err := json.Marshal{orders}
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(jsonResult)
}
```

El error se produce en las ultimas lineas, más precisamente en:`jsonResult, err := json.Marshal{orders}`

El error es:`ERROR :main.go:106:21: json.Marshal (value of type func(v any) ([]byte, error)) is not a type`

---

**INTENTE SOLUCIONARLO DE ESTA FORMA:**

```
jsonResult, err := json.Marshal {[]byte products}
```

pero lanza el siguiente error.

```
error: syntax error: unexpected products, expecting comma or }
```

**Tambien probé:**

```
ord := [] byte orders

error: syntax error: unexpected orders at end of statement
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que la sintaxis de `json.Marshal` es con llaves y no con paréntesis? ¿Revisaste la [documentación](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal)?

Comment: Si. Era eso. Muchisimas gracias!